# How to place a camera in a specific position with osgjs?

Tags: javascript, camera, webgl, openscenegraph, osg.js

How to place a camera in a specific position osgjs?

I am just learning [osgjs](http://osgjs.org/) & found no good examples for camera moving like the examples of [three js](http://threejs.org/).

In the case of threejs we can set camera position like

```
camera.position.x = 25;
camera.position.y = 50;
camera.position.z = 200;
```

but I couldn't find any with osgjs.If I'm in the wrong path of learning help me.

EDIT :

I got this far with osgjs, this moves the camera but I cant set camera up and I don't exactly understand how/what setEyePosition does.

```
        var point = [-10, -5, 10];//xyz positions
        viewer.getManipulator().setEyePosition(point);
        viewer.getManipulator().setTarget(point);
        viewer.getManipulator().setDistance(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

setEyePosition selects the camera position.

setTarget selects the point in scene where is camera is looking at.

If your geometry is located near origin, try a target = [0,0,0];

```
    var point = [-10, -5, 10]; // camera position
    var target = [0,0,0];      // looking at point
    viewer.getManipulator().setEyePosition(point);
    viewer.getManipulator().setTarget(target);
    viewer.getManipulator().setDistance(5);
```